# Get all ioctl code and which module they map

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, ioctl

By doc. , ioctl signature is `int ioctl(int fd, int request, ...)` . request is the code of ioctl.

Is there any way to know what are all the possible ioctl request code that available in my linux? And maybe to know for each code , to which kernel module is mapped?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to find all `ioctl` definitions by using the kernel source, `vim` and `ctags` program. I just use the tools from my toolbox, you can use others - maybe IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse. The essence is the same.

**Demonstration:**
(you can download this `.gif` file and open it by GIMP for example. Then all frames will be available without time limit)
[image]

**Explanation:**

**1)** I think, we are not have other ways, except digging into the kernel source. The different manuals exists, check `apropos ioctl`, but they are either incomplete or outdated. So, the most reliable way is looking at the source (if you don't have documentation from the module creator). The user process uses `ioctl` system call to send different commands to the kernel module. The module has definition and comments for each **ioctl** command. Our task is to find them.

**Note start**

You should use the same kernel source version as the `glibc` uses, not current kernel on your system, because `glibc` headers are used in the compilation of user programs. Thus, if you will use the last kernel source (or other, different from the `glibc`'s), the result could be wrong.

To find the `glibc` headers version on Ubuntu do:

```
dpkg -l linux-libc-dev*
```

**Result:**

```
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64  4.15.0-50.54    amd64           Linux Kernel Headers for development
```

Download the kernel source code with Ubuntu patches from repository into the current directory (on Ubuntu):

```
apt-get source linux-source-4.15.0
```

**Note end**

**2)** **ioctl** commands are defined in the module header file - **some_name.h**. They are just numbers, which can be calculated by special macro:

```
#define "ioctl name" __IOX("major number","command number","argument type")
```

From [documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/ioctl/ioctl-number.txt):

> If you are adding new ioctl's to the kernel, you should use the _IO
>   macros defined in **linux/ioctl.h**:
>
> ```
> _IO    an ioctl with no parameters
> _IOW   an ioctl with write parameters (copy_from_user)
> _IOR   an ioctl with read parameters  (copy_to_user)
> _IOWR  an ioctl with both write and read parameters.
> ```

But some `ioctl` definitions are not following this prescription and are not different from usual macros, like in the case of `tty` driver:

```
#define TCGETS      0x5401
```

so, we can't just `grep` header files.

**3)** The defined **ioctl** commands are used in the module source code file - **some_name.c**. There are special function - handler, which is called on each **ioctl** request. It takes the **ioctl** number as argument and switches the program execution to the corresponding branch, like:

```
switch(ioctl_cmd){
    case IOCTL_ONE:
        processing;
        break;
    case IOCTL_TWO:
        processing;
        break;
    case IOCTL_THREE:
        processing;
        break;
}
```

**4)** This **ioctl** handler is stored in the `.unlocked_ioctl` field of the `file_operations struct`:

```
static const struct file_operations sonypi_misc_fops = {
    ...      
    .unlocked_ioctl = sonypi_misc_ioctl,
```

Therefore, we can find this assignment in the source code, jump to the handler function definition by `ctags` program and look at  **ioctl** branches in the `switch` construction. Then jump further, to the specific command in the header file and look at the definition and comments.